# codeigniter 3 ERROR Undefined property

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

ERROR CODE

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$yamaha_model
>
> Filename: controllers/Yamaha.php
>
> Line Number: 12
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/billionp/domains/billionproonline.com/public_html/bpp_8/application/controllers/Yamaha.php
>   Line: 12 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   /home/billionp/domains/billionproonline.com/public_html/bpp_8/index.php
>   Line: 295 Function: require_once
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function product() on a non-object in
>   /home/billionp/domains/billionproonline.com/public_html/bpp_8/application/controllers/Yamaha.php
>   on line 12

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function product() on a non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/Yamaha.php
>
> Line Number: 12
>
> Backtrace:

Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Yamaha extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){        
    $template = array(
               'title' => 'YAMAHA',
               'heading' => 'My Heading',
               'message' => 'My Message'
          );
        $contents['row'] = $this->load->yamaha_model->product();    
        // $contents['row']          = $this->yamaha_model->product();
        $contents['cart_session'] = $this->session->userdata('cart_session');

        $template['content']      = $this->load->view('yamaha',$contents,TRUE);
        $this->load->view('template',$template);

    }

}
```

Model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Yamaha_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }   

    function product(){
        return $i = $this->db->select('*')->from('yamaha')->get()->result();
    }

    function product_detail($id){
        return $i = $this->db->select('*')->from('yamaha')->where('product_id',$id)->get()->row();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the model in constructor ?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting usage but it would appear that you cannot chain loading of the model and then calling a method. It needs to be loaded explicitly.

So change

```
$contents['row'] = $this->load->yamaha_model->product();
```

To this

```
$this->load->model('yamaha_model');
$contents['row'] = $this->yamaha_model->product();
```

Comment: Thank you, we will do as you help.